# Plot in Python / R two variables in 2 different time stamps

Tags: python, r

I am having two variables in 2 different time stamps.. requirement is to make it common time (synchronized) along X- Axis and 2 Y - Axis dual axis. I added example of our requirement

[image]

Comment: What is the data you are starting with?

Comment: It is continous data for Y1 and Y2, Time in seconds

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#Sample datasets:
df1=pd.DataFrame(); df1['time']=pd.to_datetime(['2020-1-1 02:00','2020-1-1 03:00','2020-1-1 04:00']); df1['value']=[3,6,12]
df2=pd.DataFrame(); df2['time']=pd.to_datetime(['2020-2-1 12:00','2020-2-1 13:00','2020-2-1 14:00']); df2['value']=[1,5,3]
#synchronize time using the first time element in each dataset and convert it to seconds
df1['time_sync']=(df1['time']-df1.time[0]).astype('timedelta64[s]')
df2['time_sync']=(df2['time']-df2.time[0]).astype('timedelta64[s]')
#plot over two y axises:
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df1['time_sync'],df1['value'],label='set1')
ax.set_ylim(0,13);ax.set_ylabel('set1_ylabel')

ax2=plt.twinx()
ax2.plot(df2['time_sync'],df2['value'],label='set2',c='r')
ax2.set_ylim(0,6);ax2.set_ylabel('set2_ylabel')

ax.legend()
ax2.legend()
```

[image]